# How to store sensor data into Apache Hadoop HDFS, Hive, HBase or other

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, signal-processing, sensors

Imagine you are reading millions of data rows from a CSV file. Each line shows the sensor-name, the current sensor-value and the timestamp when that value was observed.

```
key, value, timestamp
temp_x, 8°C, 10:52am
temp_x, 25°C, 11:02am
temp_x, 30°C, 11:12am
```

This relates to a signal like this:

[image: real world signal observations]

So I wonder what's the best and most efficient way to store that into Apache Hadoop HDFS. First idea is using BigTable aka HBase. Here the signal name is the row-key while the value is a column-group that saves the values over time. One could add more column-groups (as for instance statistics) to that row-key.

[image: stored in HBase]

Another idea is using a tabular (or SQL like) structure. But then you replicate the key in each row. And you have to calculate statistics on demand and store them separately (here into a second table).

[image: SQL like storage]

I wonder if there is any better idea. Once stored, I want to read that data in Python/PySpark and do data analytics and machine learning. Therefore the data should be easily accessible using a schema (Spark RDD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider to use.

- Load data from CSV file with [databricks csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)
- Cleaning the data
- Write to qarquet file (to save space and time)
- Load data from parquet file
- Analyse it
- Perhaps save as intermediate result

Comment: Thanks. That's our current approach as well.

Comment: Have you tried to save in Avro format to see the performance difference?

Comment: Yes, we tried that in different other projects and feels like Parquet is better in terms of performance.

Comment: I think Parquet is suitable for most use case except, data in the same column varies a lot, and always analysed on almost all columns. Also find a good [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957291/avro-v-s-parquet)

Comment: I have the same situation here, not sure how to handle it. So, is it reasonable to save the data as Parquet and load /analysis with sparksql or df/ds API? since it is time series data, shouldn't we store the data in any kind of nosql database as we have frequent random access to the data?