# PySpark mergeSchema on Read operation Parquet vs Avro

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have around 200 parquet files with each parquet file having a different schema and I am trying to read these parquet files using mergeSchema enabled during read and it takes almost 2 hours.
If I instead create equivalent Avro files and try to read them using the mergeSchema option on read ( Available only on Databricks runtime 9.3 LTS ) , it can do the merge within 5 minutes.

Question - Why does Parquet Schema merge on Read take too long whereas the Avro files are faster ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957291/avro-vs-parquet) answer your question ?

Comment: Yes it does to some extent. I understand that Parquet is not meant for highly denormalized data and processing or reading entire such records rather than few. Thank you.